# I'm not terminal literate, and I think I did something wrong

Tags: command-line, terminal, osx-mavericks

I was trying to resolve an issue I  had with Adobe Illustrator on OS X Mavericks, and was told to type this into the terminal:

```
sudo touch /etc/launchd.conf
```

It did not fix the issue, but it did slow my computer start up from 30 seconds to over 2 mins.  How can I reverse this command?

Answer (score 4):

All that the `touch` command that you ran did was to update the modification date and time of the `launchd.conf` file under the `/etc/` directory to the date and time when you ran the command (for example, if you ran it on say, April 13, 2014 at 8 a.m. your time, this file's modification time would've been set to that date and time). You can see the date and time on this file by typing `ls -l /etc/launchd.conf` in `Terminal.app`.

The side effect of the command was to make OS X assume that this file has changed (because of a newer modification date/time) even though its contents have not been changed. So the slower startup time you're seeing should be a temporary thing. Assuming you didn't actually change the `/etc/launchd.conf` file through any other means, the startup duration should return back to what you had before.

For information on `launchd`, the "system wide and per-user daemon/agent manager", see the following:
[Wikipedia - launchd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd)
[launchd tutorial](http://launchd.info/)
[OS X Man Pages - launchd.conf(5)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/launchd.conf.5.html)
[OS X Man Pages - launchd(8)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/launchd.8.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/8/launchd)